# Checkbox tree control for Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

Can anyone recommend a checkbox tree utility that will work with the the Spring MVC checkbox control ?

So far I've looked at Dynatree (http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/) and an extension of that to use real checkboxes (http://www.llakomy.com/articles/adding-dynatree-with-checkboxes-to-a-form/) but as you can see on the demo page (http://www.llakomy.com/articles/dynatree/tree_with_checkboxes) due to the way Dynatree works you end up with "double" checkboxes.

Is there something more appropriate to use with Spring MVC ?

Comment: The samples on Dynatree do not have double checkboxes side-by-side. Expand the source-code and you'll maybe find something: http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-select.html#

Comment: The checkboxes on Dynatree are images manipulated using CSS, I'm looking for a tree that uses real checkboxes.

Comment: I see. Maybe something like this then? http://code.google.com/p/checkboxtree/

Comment: I looked at that but when you select a child item it doesn't have that nice behaviour where you get a shaded parent, and when you unselect the child it doesn't clear the parent selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will get anything out-of-the-box.  The problem is how Spring MVC has to handle checkboxes do to the lack of foresight in the W3C in making it such that an unchecked checkbox sends no value.  Because of this, Spring MVC has no way of telling when a previously checked checkbox is unchecked.

When you use the `<form:checkbox>` tag, what you are really getting is an HTML checkbox with a hidden field and some JavaScript to tie the value of the hidden field to the checkbox.  Spring MVC then uses the value of the hidden field as an indicator that you have changed the state of the checkbox.  The end result is that Spring can tell when you have unchecked an already checked checkbox.  Trying to simulate this behavior with an off-the-shelf UI addon doesn't seem feasible without a LOT of extra coding.

So, if you have to do custom coding anyhow, why not just roll your own checkbox tree?  It seems to me that you could do this rather easily with jQuery (or plain JavaScript), some `<ul>`s and the `<form:checkbox>` tags.  One could even make it a custom JSP tag, if one were so inclined.  The JavaScript/jQuery would attach an event listener to all the checkboxes.  When a checkbox is clicked, it would simply select all child checkboxes and check them too then recurse all the parent checkboxes and mark them gray somehow (CSS anyone??).  Unchecking would do the same thing, except un-check children and un-gray the parents (if needed).

I think this would be WAY easier than trying to take something someone else wrote that was not Spring MVC compatible and try to make it work.